# How to change Pagination.Item color inside the style property in 'react-bootstrap'?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

style={{backgroundColor:'black'}}, color={...} and css styles don't work, color remains the same. All solutions are about css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could do it by selecting the 'page-link' class inside each item**

Similar to this:

```
.page-item .page-link {
  background: red;
}
```

Check this out:

[image: Edit React Bootstrap pagination example (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

This will change the color for the active Pagination button

.active .page-link{
background: blue !important
}